How do I know if there's cookies in a website (as a developer)?
When you didn't code the website, but you'll need to handle with it from now on: How do you discover all the cookies running in this website? Not only by F12. It doesn't seen to show all them...
And if a customer ask me to remove all their data (from cookies, login etc.): How do I do it?
And how do I confirm if a customer give their consent to the cookies policy?
Many thanks in advance. :)
I'm very noob. Already look for all this information in a lot of sites, but all I find is "use F12" or "cookies are kept in user browser", not saying nothing about the developer side.

Right click and select "inspect" option from the menu. There, in the tab bar, select "Application" option. You can find all cookies, local storage things etc.
